# joomla - how do I change the subdirectory in the links?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla

I had created my website on localhost under a subdirectory "joomla". Now I have ported this website to my hosting server under another subdirectory "testing". After doing this, whenever I user any of the menu items created, they try and find a page under the "joomla" folder instead of "testing"

So the links are something like http://www.mydomain.com/joomla/articleid=... instead of http://mydomain.com/testing/articleid=...

To which file should I make this change and where in the file? I tried looking into configuration.php but couldn't make much sense of where I should make the change.

This is a problem only for the menu used on the home page (my home page is a custom page) I also noticed that the home page does not directly access images in the /testing/images folder. I have to explicitly add the /testing to the image src.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the `configuration.php` file. There's a couple of variables you'll have to change:

In Joomla 1.0:

```
$mosConfig_absolute_path = 'C:/webroot/joomla';
$mosConfig_cachepath = 'C:/webroot/joomla/cache';
$mosConfig_live_site = 'http://localhost/joomla';
// change to:
$mosConfig_absolute_path = '/home/username/www/testing';
// of course, use your own path here - find it out with php_info()
$mosConfig_cachepath = '/home/username/www/testing/cache';
$mosConfig_live_site = 'http://www.mydomain.com/testing';
```

In Joomla 1.5:

```
var $log_path = '/home/username/www/testing/logs';
var $tmp_path = '/home/username/www/testing/tmp';
var $live_site = 'http://www.mydomain.com/testing';
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are going to perform this migration more than once, I'd suggest using a backup / migration tool like [joomlapack](http://www.joomlapack.net/news/releases/jp21stable.html) - it makes moving from localhost to production a less than 2 min task.  Includes the database & modules / components in the transfer as well. No issues moving from one directory structure in localhost to another in production.